# What is the correct encoding to read and write PostScript files

Tags: c#, .net, character-encoding, ghostscript, postscript

I would like to parse a PostScript file, find appropriate line number and insert a PostScript command. So, I need to read the whole file and write it as a new file along with the new commands I want to insert.

I'm using StreamReader and StreamWriter for this process.

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("filename.ps", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, true);

StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("updatedfilename.ps",true, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

When doing this, even though the commands are inserted in the appropriate location, some characters are getting lost due to encoding issues.

For example, please check the below image: In the After content, you can notice the yellow highlighted characters which got added during my write process.

[image]

In summary, I would like to know the process to read and write a PS file as it is without losing data because of encoding.

Comment: It's a "binary" file, so use byte-oriented I/O, not character-oriented I/O. "Binary" in this case just means the contents contain at least some arbitrary byte sequences that have no relationship to characters in any character encoding.

Comment: PostScript files generally contain both regular text (PS description) and binary data. If I use BinaryReader/BinaryWriter, I guess I won't be able to read the file line by line like streamreader/writer. Is there any efficient way to read a binary file line by line and write it into another file?